# What this line means in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: ubuntu, sh, zsh

In the oh-my-zsh's [upgrade tool](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/tools/upgrade.sh), I found this line(line 2):

```
current_path=${current_path/ /\\ }
```

What it did?

Additionally, this line works on mac, but on my ubuntu server it output a error says:

```
.oh-my-zsh/tools/upgrade.sh: 2: .oh-my-zsh/tools/upgrade.sh: Bad substitution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line will backslash escape the first space in the `$current_path` variable. That type of substitution isn't supported by all shells, which is why it fails on Ubuntu.

As far as I can tell, there is no good reason for that line to be there. If escaping white space where necessary, that method would be insufficient even if it worked. Worse, since the only later use of the variable has it in double quotes having backslash escapes for spaces actually breaks it.

Answer (score 11):

Updated it on Ubuntu with

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh
bash ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/upgrade.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

See [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) in the manual.

> ```
> ${name/pattern/repl}
> ${name//pattern/repl} 
>
> Replace the longest possible match of pattern in the expansion of parameter name by string repl. The first form replaces just the first occurrence, the second form all occurrences.
> ```

In essence, what the above does is prepend a backslash to the first space in `${current_path}`.

Note that this syntax is not specified by POSIX (see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) for more info), but all current `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh` versions support it. The `Bad substitution` error suggests that you are not running the `upgrade.sh` tool under the shell that you think you do (one which does not support it).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to update using commands:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh
ggpull

#or

git pull origin master
```

Comment: gl = git pull(oh-my-zsh):
`cd ~/.oh-my-zsh && gl`